# I keep getting this error when trying to determine average grade,

Tags: java

```
   double average = calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5);
   System.out.println("The average is: ");
   determineGrade(average);

   public static double calcAverage(int grade1, int grade2, int grade3, int grade4, int grade5) {
      double average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5) / 5;
      return average;        
  }
```

I keep getting the error where it says `determineGrade(average)`, The error says:

> This method must return a result of type double

Comment: Sorry, I'm sleepy. You're feeding your method args of type int and expecting it to kick out a double. Use your Google Fu and search for "cast int to double" and then delete this questions.

Comment: Not enough code included to tell what is going on. Where is the code for `determineGrade()`?

Comment: Where is the function `determineGrade`?

Answer (score 1):

All your inputs are ints. So your result will be an int. You need to cast at least one int to double then your result would be a double as well.

double average = (double) (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5) / 5

Answer (score 1):

That's because in `determineGrade` you return nothing. You only print something, but return nothing. So, please make the return type of `determineGrade` void, or, at least make it return something in `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok sorry, but the rest of the code comes as follows,


import java.util.*;

  public class Stock
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     int grade1=0;
     int grade2=0;
     int grade3=0;
     int grade4=0;
     int grade5=0;

  // All of the below are gathering input from user
  System.out.println("What is the first grade?");

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   grade1=input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("What is the second grade?");
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    grade2=input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Whar is the third grade?");
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    grade3=input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("What is the fourth grade?");
   Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
   grade4=input.nextInt();

   System.out.println("What is the fifth grade?");
   Scanner input5 = new Scanner(System.in);
   grade5=input.nextInt();


   double average = calcAverage(grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5);

   System.out.println("The average is: ");

     determineGrade(average);

  }
  public static double calcAverage(int grade1, int grade2, int grade3, int grade4, int grade5)
  {
    double average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5) / 5;

        return average;

  }

  public static double determineGrade(double average)


    {

        if (average>90)

        {

            System.out.println("You got an A");

        }

        else if (average>=80)

        {

            System.out.println("You got a B");

        }

        else if (average>=70)

        {

            System.out.println("You got a C");

        }

        else if (average>=60)

        {

            System.out.println("You got a D");

        }
        else if (average<60)



        {

            System.out.println("You got an F");


        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you need to add missing code, edit your original question. Don't add an answer to your own question because it's not an answer, is it? Now did you search for "cast int to double?" Also, check out the SO [help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help). It'll help you use this site to get better answers.